# Cannot create partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I've recently installed Ubuntu to dual boot along side my Windows 7 installation, they're both installed on the same SSD which all seems to be working fine.

I have another 3TB HHD which I use for general storage, so far I've got 50% of it being used for Windows, 50GB being used as a swap area for moving files between Windows & Linux if needed & the rest I want to format for Linux; this is where I'm having a problem.

I'm using the "Disks" utility which was fine for creating the 50GB area for swapping files between Windows & Linux but it doesn't want to partition the remainder of the hard drive. This is the error message I get:

Don't know how to create partitions this partition table of type `(null)' (udisks-error-quark, 0)

These are the settings I'm using, partitions size 1450GB, Erase quick, Type Luks + Ext4, Name Linux storage, Passphrase long & complicated.

I'm not sure if this is related in anyway but when I installed Linux I didn't create a swap partition as I have 16GB of RAM which I'm probably going to increase at some point and as far as I'm aware you can create a swap partition later down the line if needed.

If anyone is wondering why there's a swap area for Windows & Linux it's because the Windows partitions are encrypted and the software I used doesn't run on Linux.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure this out, if you create the partition without encryption then format it again with encryption it seems to work.

Seems odd that you're allowed to select the encryption option at a stage that it will not work.